# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields Google Maps field is not displayed

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

Hello.

I guess it's very simple, but I cannot find the solution of my problem anywhere. I want to add the "google-maps" field with the plugin Advanced Custom Fields (and there is plenty of instructions for this action in the internet). But ACF doesn't give me such option. In the list of possible types of fields there is no "google map", see the screenshot with the available types. Should I switch it on somehow previously, and if yes, where is the setting? Thank you.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJA6Z.png)

Wordpress 4.5.2, ACF 4.4.7

Comment: In your screenshot you have not scrolled down far enough. The `Google Map` field type is located under the `jQuery` heading which is the section below the lowest one that's visible in your screenshot.

Comment: Ah. I just haven't noticed the scroll. Thank you so much =)